# Remove observer from third party extension

Tags: magento2, event-observer, overrides

I have installed a blog module onto my Magento 2 platform. This blog module has an observer which automatically adds a new menu item into the primary navigation. I wish to stop this.

The `events.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before">
        <observer name="aw_blog_add_topmenu_items" instance="Aheadworks\Blog\Observer\AddBlogToTopmenuItemsObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

As you can see it references the observer that adds the link into the primary navigation. Deleting `events.xml` solves my problem, but I'm looking for a method that doesn't involve modifying of core module files.

Answer (score 14):

You still can disable observers. In Magento 1 it was done with `<type>disabled</type>`, in Magento 2 it's `disabled="true"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before">
        <observer name="aw_blog_add_topmenu_items"
                  instance="Aheadworks\Blog\Observer\AddBlogToTopmenuItemsObserver"
                  disabled="true" />
    </event>
</config>
```

If you add this modified `events.xml` file to a custom module and make the custom module depend on Aheadworks_Blog, it should override the original one.

Comment: I'm curious if the observer merging process uses only the `name` attribute (seeing how it's unique). In which case, you could omit the somewhat long `instance` property: `<observer name="aw_blog_add_topmenu_items" disabled="true"`.

Comment: as per vendor/magento/framework/Event/etc/events.xsd only `name` required - all other attributes are optional